# WP plugin External API, Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have set up my WordPress plugin using a boilerplate. I have created a custom post type for my plugin. This is where I am at.

Where I am trying to go.. 
I would like to be able to create post that I have made. It is a reports Post. So in the create, I would like to customize the user interface. I want to be able to populate the options based on an external api call. One selection will populate the next selection using another external api call based on what it returned. 
Then create the post.

When clicking on the post I would like to be able to use the metadata/data that came from the creation of the post type to make several api calls and populate a spreadsheet that will be displayed on the page.

I have been looking for tutorials for this and have not been able to find any. I have looked over the wp plugin development handbook and do not see a clear picture on how I can do this.

Is it possible to implement this way or should I try to make everything custom (which will be a headache especially when trying to comply to the rules, this is something I want to publish to the wordpress plugin repository eventually).

I would also like this to have a similar functionality on the front end.

Here is the process I would like the user to have.
Custom Reports page loads

-> lists all of the reports created and has a button to create a new report

-> create new report page has drop down lists. The first drop down list has x amount of options that are populated using an external api with a header that has the users credentials within it, the user selects one option. The next dropdown list is populated by an api get request using the selection from the first dropdown list. The next dropdown list is populated using an external api get request's response from the selection from the second dropdown list and so on..

-> would like to apply filters but that piece can come later

-> The user generates the report

->Then the user saves the report

When clicking on a report within the reports page, a report will be generated using the saved selections from the create report. This generation will be handled by api calls using the selections as headers. The response will then be parsed through and filled into a spreadsheet that will be displayed for the user.

The user can then export the report into a pdf or csv file.

My main question right now is there a way to implement this type of logic using custom post types within wordpress?